# Does exiftool require the complete file for extracting metadata

Tags: exiftool

This question is about **extraction** of metadata only.

Is it required for exiftool to get a complete file for propperly working?

**Scenario:**

I want to extract the metadata of a 20 GB video file. Do I need to provide exiftool with the complete file (via stdin), or is it enough to provide it with a certain amount of bytes.

**Motivation:**

I am programatically (golang) calling exiftool in a streaming context and want to have the extraction as fast as possible. Magic numbers for filetypes work with the first 33 bytes and I am wondering if that is possible with the exiftool metadata as well.

Comment: Make sure you're also running exiftool in batch mode, so you don't have to pay the perl-spinup-fee for every file. https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#stay_open-FLAG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends upon the file and the location of the metadata within that file.

There are a couple of threads on the subject on the ExifTool forums ([link 1](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=6080.0), [link 2](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=7579.0)) and Phil Harvey, the author, says that about half the time the in the case of MP4/MOV videos, the metadata is at the end of the file.

Using the [`-fast` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#fast-NUM) might help.  I've done some quick tests using cURL and a large image file (see the second to the last example under [Piping Examples](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#PIPING-EXAMPLES)) and in that case cURL didn't download the whole image file, just enough to extra the metadata.  It might be different with a video file though, as I haven't tested that situation.

Comment: Comment by Phil in the forum "If you use -fast, you may not see any metadata that is stored in a trailer after the image."

Comment: For my use case I would answer the question with no, as you can not rely on `-fast` to give you all metadata. As getting all available ones is essential for me, I will have to check the complete files.